# C2DMReg - handleRequest caught java.net.UnknownHostException: android.clients.google.com

Tags: android, android-c2dm, google-cloud-messaging, unknown-host

My question is related to **[C2DMReg] handleRequest caught java.net.UnknownHostException: android.clients.google.com** I found some [question in StackOverflow with the same title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9597542/c2dmreg-handlerequest-caught-java-net-unknownhostexception-android-clients-goog) that has been marked as duplicate. But the duplicate that is mentioned has nothing to do with the matter at concern here. This is related to the new GCM - not C2DM.

My code sources are [from the GCM tutorial in Android API Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gcm.html#writing_apps)

---

My function for registering the device with GCM is as follows:

```
public void register_device(Context c){
    Intent registrationIntent = new Intent("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER");
    registrationIntent.putExtra("app", PendingIntent.getBroadcast(c, 0, new Intent(), 0));
    registrationIntent.putExtra("sender", c.getResources().getString(R.string.SERVER_API_KEY));
    Log.i("GCM", "Starting service for registration Intent");
}
```

My BroadCastReceiver class is as follows:

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public final void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i("GCM", "Received broadcast from Intent: " + intent);
        MyIntentService.runIntentInService(context, intent);
        setResult(MainActivity.RESULT_OK, null, null);
    }
}
```

My Manifest file contains the permissions for MyBroadcastReceiver as follows

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<permission
    android:name="com.mangoesmobile.praxis.pusher.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.mangoesmobile.praxis.pusher.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<application>
    <receiver
        android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="com.mangoesmobile.praxis.pusher" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

The logs show my custom log from the register_device function() `Starting service for registration Intent`

and then shows `[C2DMReg] handleRequest caught java.net.UnknownHostException: android.clients.google.com`
 with tag `C2DMRegistrar`

It never shows my custom log `Received broadcast from Intent` from MyBroadcastReceiver. So it never reaches MyBroadcastReceiver i believe. I am not able to figure why would this happen.

I am not using an emulator. I am using my own device and it is registered with a google account.

Comment: How about trying the [Demo](http://www.lalit3686.blogspot.in/2012/07/android-steps-to-run-gcm-demo.html)?

Comment: looks like your device has some connectivity problem - android.clients.google.com - should be accessible - try adb shell ping android.clients.google.com

Comment: sometimes i pity myself as a software engineer......... for the last several hours i forgot to turn on the Wifi of my device. VERY SORRY FOR THAT.